# Calling another program with exec()

Tags: memory, exec, fork, shared

I want to use another program using exec function in c. Actually after the fork I want to create random number in child and send to parent using shared memory. But whenever i use exec function i have this error and here is my code:

```
    int shmid;

shmid = shmget(key, 80,0700|IPC_CREAT);
ptr = (int *) shmat (shmid, NULL , 0); 
i=fork();

if(i==0)
{
    printf("1");
    exec("p2","p2",shmid);
}
else if(i>0)
{
    printf("anam");
}
else
{
    exit(1);
}
```

p1.c:31:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
p1.c:31:3: warning: missing sentinel in function call [-Wformat]

So my question is how can I use exec only writing program's name as parameter.

Comment: Why not add the 'C' tag so that C programmers see this?

Comment: There is no such thing as `exec`.

Comment: For asking a question here, especially something this complex, it is best to create an "[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)" otherwise - for example - we have no way to tell "which is line 31?", "which headers did you include?"

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> exec("p2","p2",shmid);
> ```

There is no `exec` standard function. I assume you meant `execl`, in which case it should be:

```
execl("/full/path/to/p2", "p2", shmid_to_string, NULL);
```

To convert `shmid` to a string you can use `snprintf`.

Comment: I see.But i need to use only programs name not the path

Comment: @user3609616 Then maybe try `execlp` ?